# PasswordCredential Error when attempting to run jar in ACC

Tags: database, jakarta-ee, glassfish, persistence

I am trying to run a stand-alone application, which will be executed in a application client container.

I have glassfish running and have setup the relevant JDBC pool and resource (pinging the connection pool shows a successful message).

Running the program with:

> appclient -client bookstore.jar

results in a large error stack (i've included only a small section):

```
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.2.0.v20110202-r8913): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: No PasswordCredential found
```

It appears that PasswordCredential is causing the problem, however I think I have setup the database connections correctly.

Any ideas on what could be causing this?

Comment: http://amanica.blogspot.com/2009/02/no-passwordcredential-found.html Have you restarted GF after setting up your pool?

Comment: restarting Glassfish fixes this, thanks @Preston.